Can't figure out how to add an element based on a template in VueJS
I'm trying to use Vue to update my static HTML. What I need is to update some elements (say, change the inner HTML, or icon, or some part of it), and add a new one to the DOM. My requirement is to use templates for adding a new element because creating is dynamically with JS is tedious as they could be complicated.
Here is my code that updates the element "counter":
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Counter</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="list">
     <div class="counter" id="a">5</div>
  </div>
 <button>update</update>

  <script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#a',
      data: {
        counter: 5
      },
      mounted() {
        this.counter = 10;
      },
      template: '<div>{{ counter }}</div>'
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>


How to change it to add a new "counter" element to the "list"?
How to change it to update the existing counter with the button click and without completely rewriting it?


components are needed for #1.  I'm not sure I understand question 2.  You would just add a click event handler similar to vanilla JavaScript.  Not sure why "completely rewriting it" would be a concern.  Also, is it a requirement to use vue 2, which has reached end of life, instead of vue 3?  do you need to use CDN instead of build step (i.e. npm + vite)?  With a build step you can use SFC .vue files

@yoduh Thanks! Can you please give me an example how it can be done the components? I'm familiar with the concept but struggle to implement in my case.
Regarding #2. In my example - the code updates the value but completely replaces the component. Well, it may be not bad. I don't understand why.

@yoduh Okay, I can formalize why I don't want the element to be completely rewritten - because it was generated on the server side with the data, set of rules, etc. All I want is to update the value.

As with Vue 3 you can mount the app into a Vue template like this:


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.4.8/vue.global.min.js"></script>
<div class="list" id="app">
   <div class="counter"> {{ counter }}</div>
   <button @click="counter++">update</update>
</div>

<script>
     Vue.createApp({
      data: () => ({
        counter: 5
      }),
      mounted() {
        this.counter = 10;
      },
    }).mount('#app');
</script>



